# SQL - Append the contents of multiple similar columns together?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, rows, multiple-columns

I have a table for the most popular baby names from the last century in the structure seen below:

```
Rank | 1904 | 1914 | 1924 | 1934 | 1944 | 1954...
--------------------------------------------------
 1   | Max   | Tom | Ben | James | Bill | James
 2   | John  | Bill| Tom | John  | James| Bill
```

I am trying to append all the names from the columns 1904-1994 into a single column like:

```
Names | 1904 | 1914 | 1924 | 1934 | 1944 | 1954...
--------------------------------------------------
 Max   | 1   | -    | -    | -    | -    | -
 John  | 2   | -    | -    | 2    | -    | -
 Tom   | -   | 1    | 2    | -    | -    | -
 Bill  | -   | 2    | -    | -    | 1    | 2
 James | -   | -    | -    | 1    | 2    | 1
 Ben   | -   | -    | 1    | -    | -    | -
```

What would you suggest?

While I am looking for something specific to solve the problem I am having above, I also really want to know in general how to combine columns together **where all the rows are added underneath** unlike || or concat which literally adds the rows together.

Comment: This looks like a spreadsheet as opposed to a relational structure. What's the table definition? Are there actual columns named "1904", "1914"...

Comment: Yes, this is an imported table csv from the UK Census dataset. Not the best format I know.

Comment: Any chance you can un-pivot the data into a (name, decade,rank) table? That would be much more conducive to proper SQL queries.

Comment: I would love to and I was hoping that there would be someway I could do this with SQL over programatically as there are many tables similar to this.